# How to extend connection timeout in node-template, when joining a private network?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, libp2p

I was following the [Creating Your Private Network](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customchain) tutorial.
I have a running the bootnode in my local machine, and I want a new participant from AWS to  join in my network. But somehow, i keep getting `0 peers`.

I added the logs `RUST_LOG=debug` and found this:

```
2021-08-04 02:06:40.563 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_dns: Dialing /ip4/130.105.xxx.xxx/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooxxxNr    
2021-08-04 02:06:40.563 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_tcp: dialing 130.105.xxx.xxx:30333    
2021-08-04 02:06:40.563 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_swarm: Connection attempt to PeerId("12D3KooxxxNr") via "/ip4/130.105.xxx.xxx/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooxxxNr" failed with Transport(Other(Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout })). Attempts remaining: 2.    
2021-08-04 02:06:40.563 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_kad::behaviour: Last remaining address '/ip4/130.105.xxx.xxx/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooxxxNr' of peer '12D3KooxxxNr' is unreachable: Pending connection: Transport error: Timeout has been reached.
```

I read it somewhere, that it takes [5 minutes](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-examples/issues/79#issuecomment-567217331) to connect.
How do I increase the timeout period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your local machine doesn't have a public IP address.

I recommend you to set your AWS as the bootnode then connect from your local machine.

Comment: huh okay, i understand. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I think you could also configure port forwarding on your router connected to you ISP for the ports needed to your machine to enable this. But you likely have a dynamic IP. So best to use DDNS setup. Do note that this can lead to downtime for that node though, and likely should not be used as a boot node, instead static IPs should be used.